# calling bash from python

Tags: python, bash, stdout, stdin

I have a python script which calles a bash script.
The bash script compiles several modules and I would like to seethe result of the compilation  printed on screen while running.

Most important, anyway, is that the bash script requires a run time quite some few input from the user.
How can I make my python script give stdin/stdout to the bash script?

For the moment I am using

```
(_stat, _resl) = commands.getstatusoutput("./myBashScript")
```

but in this way the user is not promped of anything while the bash is running...

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `subprocess` (as you should!) and don't specify stdin/stdout/stderr, they'll operate normally. For example:

```
# lol.py
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'])
p.wait()

$ python lol.py
hello
hello
catting
catting
```

You could also process `stdout` as you like:

```
# lol.py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()

print "\n\nOutput was:"
print p.stdout.read()

$ python lol.py
hello
catting

^D

Output was:
hello
catting
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "as you should"? I'd like to know whether `subprocess` is a good choice for my situation. I'm not asking for a comprehensive essay, but knowing why you think the OP should use `subprocess` in his situation would help.

Comment: @LarsH I just meant that `subprocess` is now the preferred module for any kind of process-calling, rather than `commands`, `os.popen`, `os.system`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [envoy library](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy).

```
import envoy
r = envoy.connect('./myBashScript')
r.send('input text') # send info on std_in
r.expect('output text') # block until text seen
print r.std_out # print whatever is in the std_out pipe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.system open a terminal window for that, such as gnome-terminal, to run the bash script.